# gnu screen command that stops running then switching to another tab

Tags: bash, gnu-screen

I use GNU screen to keep a bunch of tabs open in my terminal session, and I would like to have a bash command, `watch -n 1 ps aux | grep something`, that runs when I am looking at that screen tab, but stops running when I don't have any window displaying at the tab. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

no can do.  this cannot be automized.  sorry.

workaround:
use a command alias to start such a tab/window, eg
"bind S screen ~/bin/myscript".
put screen into zombie mode (eg with ":zombie z").
end the script when not required any more.
switch to tab and restart process with ctrl-space.